# MySQL-Python & Django 1.5.0: no module named mysql.base error

Tags: python, mysql, django, ubuntu, mysql-python

I am trying to create database table with Django by `python manage.py syncdb` and get an error `Error was: No module named mysql.base`.
I know there are many questions like this on the web but none one of them helped me.

Python version: `2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:16:07) \n[GCC 4.6.3]`.

Django version: `(1, 5, 0, 'final', 0)`.

MySQL-Python version: `MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-linux-i686`.

System information: `Linux Marlon 3.5.0-26-generic #42~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Mar 11 22:19:42 UTC 2013 i686 athlon i386 GNU/Linux`

MySQL version: `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.29, for debian-linux-gnu (i686) using readline 6.2`

My `setting.py` file:

```
...
DATABASES = {
  'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
    'NAME': 'a',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
    # The following settings are not used with sqlite3:
    'USER': 'a',
    'PASSWORD': 'a',
    'HOST': 'a',                      # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
    'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default.
  }
}
...
```

Error code:

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 453, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 272, in fetch_command
klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 77, in load_command_class
module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
__import__(name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 8, in <module>
from django.core.management.sql import custom_sql_for_model, emit_post_sync_signal
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/sql.py", line 9, in <module>
from django.db import models
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
backend = load_backend(connection.settings_dict['ENGINE'])
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 34, in __getattr__
return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 93, in __getitem__
backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 45, in load_backend
raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'django.db.backends.mysql' isn't an available database backend.
Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
u'oracle', u'postgresql_psycopg2', u'sqlite3'
Error was: No module named mysql.base`
```

And `import MySQLdb` works fine in the interactive shell.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like something is wrong with your Django installation: it's listing the packages available under `django.db.backends`, and doesn't mention `mysql` for some reason. I would try deleting Django completely and re-installing it.

(I'm also confused by the fact that you have Django 1.5 under dist-packages. That's for packages provided by the distribution, and Django 1.5 is too new to have made it into any distributions yet. Maybe you have two conflicting installations?)

Comment: You're right! There're two installations! Maybe I installed from https://www.djangoproject.com/download/ latest official and latest development versions both)
Reinstalling with `apt-get install python-django` after uninstalling helped me. Thank you!